# Can I fix the screen on my macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, repair

I dropped my Macbook the other day, and when I opened it, there were lines on my screen.

- I have a pretty solid cover as a case and it was about a 3-foot drop.
- The colored vertical lines tend to shift whenever I move the screen.
- There aren't any cracks on the screen.

I don't know what's wrong with I t, and I'm not sure if I can contact anyone to fix it. Here is a link to what my screen looks like, I
   also added a video of the shifting lines. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv5Ce.jpg

Is there
   anything I can do?

Comment: Post your pic to imgur, gyazo etc at full size, post the link here in comments & someone can get it properly inlined here for you. Better to see the real screen than someone else's.

Comment: Agreed @Tetsujin - my answer applies to the image - not necessarily to Simplicity's Mac until we see the actual damage.

Comment: @bmike imgur.com/gallery/M0FbvBe I added an image of my screen and a small clip of the shifting lines

Comment: Wonderful image. My answer applies directly to your very not wonderful circumstances. Since there is no case damage and the screen is up damaged, I would not open your mac to explore unless you are committed to spending to repair all the potential. damage. Run it as long as you can so you can build up confidence the main board is healthy.

Answer (score 1):

Buying a replacement display assembly would repair that damage. It's not a super hard repair, but you could break the rest of the Mac while it's open so if you read the guide for your Mac on iFixit.com or another place where people make DIY repair manuals - you can choose to pay a technician or see if DIY is worth an attempt.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834

Also - you don't need to fix this - you could use your Mac in closed clamshell mode with an external display - it won't be portable, but an external display is cheaper and larger than the built in one and you would get to use that external with any computer and not sink the cost on the custom display as a service part.

Since your movement changes the lines - it's a fracture / disconnect of the wires to run the display and the panel that broke - not that the logic board or GPU have issues as the most likely failure mode. Once you get in to the Mac - you may find the logic board also cracked - so be sure you are OK getting it repaired ($800 for MacBook - $1200 for MacBook Pro) if all the parts are damaged and not just the screen. When you open, like Humpty Dumpty - if the case is holding things together marginally, when you open the case, you may find / cause more damage.